# Facebook documentation or how to learn Facebook API for Android

Tags: android, facebook, documentation

Last few days I was struggling with these Facebook implementation things and read a lot of available materials which is a pile of inconsistent scrap. 
Currently I'm at stage of creating first login buttons, but classes that Im using according to 2 year old tutorials, like this:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xndi6s9Tn_U

are now deprecated. I also found that a lot of people complain about facebook official documentation because it's deprecated, not working or not complete. But there are things that needs to be programmed. So my question is simple and I would really like to know your suggestions and opinions:

***How it is possible to learn basics of programming Facebook API that works in 2014 and where we can find usable material for this?***

Comment: there is only one way and that way is read here [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) , first download and run the examples they had given after that read the code. hope this will clear things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usable materials goes together with Facebook SDK for Android by sample applications. Take look, code is best documentation. Login process it's pretty simple.

I was implemented some basic things recently (09.2014) and for me looks like Facebook documentation is good enough in comparison with open source projects. Problem is only they updates SDK and API's too frequently by their dao. And it makes most of 3d party tutorials outdated, but still useful if it's not 2 years old.

First read [Facebook SDK tutorial for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious) carefully.

Second look into code of sample application.

Try to find useful code samples in [GitHub](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook)